Is it possible that the roots of a biquadratic equation will be in A.P. , G.P. , H.P.?
Is it possible that the roots of the biquadratic equation $ax^{4}+bx^{2}+c=0$ $(a,b,c\in R , a \not = 0)$ will be in A.P., G.P., H.P. ?
Where
A.P. means Arithmetic Progression.
G.P. means Geometric Progression.
H.P. means Harmonic Progression.
Let me tell my thoughts :
I took into consideration many biquadratic equations like
$x^{4}-3x^{2}+2=0 \tag{EQ1}$
$x^{4}-6x^{2}+5=0 \tag{EQ2}$
$2x^{4}-3x^{2}+1=0 \tag{EQ3}$
Now for $EQ1$ , the roots are
{$-\sqrt{2}, -1, 1, \sqrt{2}$}
For $EQ2$ the roots are :
{$-\sqrt{5}, -1, 1, \sqrt{5}$}
Similarly for $EQ3$ the roots are
{$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, -1, 1, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$}
But till now I have not found any biquadratic equations whose roots are in A.P., G.P., H.P.
Please help me out with this concept.

Surely you can find a (biquadratic) equation with the roots $-3, -1, 1, 3$ ...

@Sahaj I think they intend to have the $x^3$-coefficient zero. The title may mislead though.

Indeed, I didnt see that

The only root possible in G.P. is $1, -1, 1, -1$ or $-1, 1, -1, 1$, since Biquadratic equations always have roots in the form of $\pm\alpha,\pm\beta$.

Yes the co-efficient of $x^{3}$ is $0$

@MartinR I can't understand how those numbers can be in geometric progression..

@Sahaj Those numbers are in arithmetic progression.

Ok, but the question asks for said roots to be in AP, GP, HP simultaneously (as is apparent to me by wording, otherwise this seems a bit too trivial imo). So that obviously doesn't work.

@Sahaj What sort of sequence of four numbers do you imagine is in all three kinds of progressions simultaneously? I think that only happens if all four numbers are equal. This is a bizarre interpretation.

The Equation $X^4-10X^2+9=0$ has roots $-3,-1,+1,+3$ which are in AP.
More generally , the Equation $X^4-10P^2X^2+9P^4=0$ has roots $-3P,-P,+P,+3P$ which are in AP.
We can not have GP there , because these roots have Signs $-,-,+,+$ (in general) hence there is no Common Ratio which can convert first Negative root to the next Negative root yet convert that to the next Positive root.
That automatically implies that there is no way to get roots which are in AP+GP+HP.
I am ignoring trivial cases like all roots are Equal , all roots are Zero , all roots have Modulus $1$ , etc.

A common negative ratio could, in theory give negative-positive-negative-positive roots, so the sign argument doesn't work.

I think that you did not read my answer right , @jjagmath , I got the AP terms which are $-,-,+,+$ , then I am saying that this Case can not have GP. I am not talking about "GP in general" at all.

Oh, I see. I think that the OP is not asking for a progression that is AP, GP and HP at the same time, but three equations with its roots on each type of progression.

I thought about that , though then the Post would be closed [ Due to asking too many things in one Post ] while the answer by Sahaj says "no polynomial with real roots exists such that its roots are in arithmetic, geometric, and harmonic progression at the same time" , like-wise the answer by Piquito says "Deduce from the given AP" indicating that all three occur together. Over-all that is my "Interpretation" too , @jjagmath , that Equations with all three are wanted here.

For A.P. we have $(x+3a)(x+a)(x-a)(x-3a)=x^4-10a^2x^2+9a^4$
For H.P. we deduce from the given A.P. $9a^4x^4-10a^2x^2+1$
For G.P. it is not possible because $r+r^2+r^3+r^4=\dfrac{r^5-1}{r-1}=0$

The question is unclear about whether the four roots of one polynomial must be in arithmetic, geometric, and harmonic progression at the same time, or whether it is enough to find different polynomials for each kind of progression.
The polynomial can be rewritten in the form
$$ ax^4 + bx^2 + c = a(x - p)(x + p)(x - q)(x + q) \tag1 $$
where the roots are $\pm p$ and $\pm q$.
(I'll leave it to you to figure out why.)
Geometric progression
If the roots of the polynomial are in G.P. with non-zero factor $r$ between consecutive roots, then since $p$ and $-p$ are both terms in the G.P. we must have
$-p = r^k p$ for some non-zero (positive or negative) integer $k$.
So either $p = 0$, in which case the only possible G.P. is $0,0,0,0$
(which is in A.P. but not H.P) or $p\neq 0$ and $r^k = -1$, in which case (assuming we are working only in real numbers) we must have $r = -1$ and the G.P. is something of the form $r_1, -r_1, r_1, -r_1$ where $r_1 \neq 0$ is one of the roots, which cannot be arranged in either A.P. or H.P.
Arithmetic progression
If the roots are in A.P., assume WLOG that it is an increasing progression and that $0 \leq p \leq q$, from which it follows that $-q \leq -p \leq 0$, so the four terms of the progression are $-q,-p,p,q$. This can be an A.P. only if $-p - (-q) = p - (-p) = q - p$,
which is true if and only if $q = 3p.$
The A.P. is therefore $-3r_1, -r_1, r_1, 3r_1$ where $r_1$ is one of the roots;
this cannot be arranged in G.P. (unless $r_1=0$) but it can be arranged in H.P.
(if $r_1 \neq 0$):
$-r_1, -3r_1, 3r_1, r_1$.
Harmonic progression
The roots are in H.P. if and only if their reciprocals are in A.P.; applying the reasoning from the A.P. case to the reciprocals of the roots, we find that those reciprocals must be $-\dfrac3{r_1}, -\dfrac1{r_1}, \dfrac1{r_1}, \dfrac3{r_1}$,
where $r_1$ is one of the roots.
The roots are then in the A.P. $-r_1, -\frac13 r_1, \frac13 r_1, r_1$.
Combining this finding with the findings in the A.P. case, we see that the roots are in H.P. if and only if they are in A.P. and not all zero.
Polynomials
Knowing the four roots $\pm p$ and $\pm q$, we can use Equation $(1)$ to find the coefficients $a, b, c$. In all cases below we can take $a$ to be any real number other than zero.
For the G.P. and A.P. $0,0,0,0$: $ax^4 + bx^2 + c = a(x-0)^4 = ax^4$; $b = c = 0$.
For the G.P. $r_1, -r_1, r_1, -r_1$ where $r_1 \neq 0$,
$$ax^4 + bx^2 + c = a(x-r_1)^2(x+r_1)^2 = a(x^4 - 2r_1^2 x^2 + r_1^4);$$
so $b = 2ar_1^2$ and $c = ar_1^4$ for an arbitrary non-zero $r_1$.
For the A.P. and H.P. $-3r_1, -r_1, r_1, 3r_1$ where $r_1 \neq 0$,
$$ax^4 + bx^2 + c = a(x+3r_1)(x+r_1)(x-r_1)(x-3r_1) = a(x^4 - 10r_1^2 x^2 + 9r_1^4);$$ so $b = 10ar_1^2$ and $c = 9ar_1^4$ for an arbitrary non-zero $r_1$.

The answer is no polynomial of form $ax^4 + bx^2 + c$ with real roots exists such that its roots are in arithmetic, geometric, and harmonic progression at the same time.
Proof: If we take $t=x^2$ we have $at^2+bt+c$. Suppose it has roots $t=\alpha$ and $t=\beta$ which are both non-negative. We have $x\in \{-\sqrt{\alpha}, -\sqrt{\beta}, \sqrt{\alpha}, \sqrt{\beta}\}$. To ensure that the terms can exist in harmonic progression all the roots must be not $0$. Thus we have $\alpha, \beta >0$. We are given that these roots arranged in some manner form a geometric progression and in some arrangement give an arithmetic progression.

Fact $1$: The four terms in geometric progression must alternate sign.

Proof: Proceed via contradiction; suppose two consecutive terms $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ have the same sign; then the common ratio $r = \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} > 0$ giving that $a_{n+2}$ has the same sign as its predecessor which is not posssible since there are only two terms which are positive and negative each.
Since three consecutive terms $a,b,c$ in geometric progression satisfy $b^2 = ac$; using fact $1$ we can check that in all geometric progressions of the roots, $\alpha = \beta$.

Fact $2$: Three consecutive terms in arithmetic progression can not alternate sign.

Proof: Suppose $a_1>0$, $a_2<0$ and $a_3>0$. The common difference $d = a_2 - a_1 < 0$. Thus $a_3 = a_2 + d < 0$; contradiction. Similarly for $a_1<0$, $a_2>0$ and $a_3<0$. $d = a_2 - a_1 >0$ so $a_3 = a_2 + d > 0$ so $a_3> 0$; contradiction.
Combining fact $2$ and $\alpha = \beta$, we realize if the roots form a geometric progression then they can't form an arithmetic progression in any order. Checking this is just a matter of calculation, which I've removed from the answer for the sake of readability.

Great, a ghost downvote without explanation.

Actually {$-\alpha,\alpha,\alpha,-\alpha$} is not in A.P. I think the downvote was for that reason.

Regardless, I've edited my answer to hopefully make it a bit more clear.
